# Explicit calculation of the twisted sheaf in a blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be the nodal rational curve, let $Y:= \mathbb{P}^1 \overset{\nu}{\to} X$ be the normaliztion map. If we let $\omega_X$ be the sheaf of regular differentials on $X$ then we have the obvious inclusion

$$ \nu_*\omega_{Y} \hookrightarrow \omega_X. $$

Viewing $\nu_*\omega_{Y} \otimes \omega_X^\vee$ as an ideal sheaf $I$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$ we can construct the blowup $\pi: \tilde X \to X$ corresponding to $I$.

The fiber over the node is a newly formed $\mathbb{P}^1$, call it $E$. The blowup construction gives us a canonical line bundle on $\tilde X$ denoted by $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde X}(1)$. My question is

> What is the degree of $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde X}(1)|_E$?

Comment: Are you sure that the fiber over the node is a $\mathbb P^1$ ?

Comment: Yes the ideal has a two dimensional stalk at the node, roughly speaking these are the two stalks of $\omega_Y$ over the note. Hence the projectivization gives a $\mathbb{P}^1$. To see this, note that the fiber of a projective bundle can be calculated by pulling back the ideal (as a stand alone sheaf) and then forming the projective bundle. This should be in Vakil's notes.

Comment: Emre, I think what paf might have been getting at is that you never explicitly mentioned that your curve is immersed in (I'm assuming) $\mathbb P^2$. The way the question is phrased, it kind of sounds like you're blowing up an abstract rational nodal curve, for which the exceptional divisor is indeed just the two points lying over the node (this is exactly the same as the normalization in this case). But it looks like you are implicitly referring to the embedded resolution, which as you said brings the $\mathbb P^1$ you get from blowing up the plane along for the ride.

Comment: @TabesBridges I am doing an abstract blowup and we nevertheless get a $\mathbb{P}^1$ over the node. Admittedly, this is a bit surprising because the usual sort of blow-up construction produces an exceptional *divisor* and not a *component*. Still, I simply used the ideal sheaf $I$ to form the graded sheaf of algebras $\bigoplus_d I^d$ and then I took the relative Proj construction. This is the abstract (or intrinsic) blowup which doesn't require an embedding. Calculating the fiber over a point is just a matter of repeating the proj construction with the pullback of $I$, hence my comment above.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see, you weren't doing a resolution of singularities per say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in Vakil's notes that you can not only calculate the fiber of a blowup by restricting the graded algebra to the point, but you can also calculate the pullback of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to that fiber with the same construction.

Therefore, we need only focus our attention on the node $n \in X$. Pulling back the ideal sheaf $I$ to the node, we get a 2-dimensional vector space. Over a point, there are no mysteries: The Proj construction gives the usual $\mathbb{P}^1$ together with its degree 1 line bundle.

**PS:** I was expecting a more interesting answer because of some contextual reasons, which is why I asked. Sorry for this rather dull solution.

**PPS:** Something more interesting happens on $Y$ whose map to $X$ factors through $\tilde X$. There is a canonical map $\mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathcal{O}$ on $\tilde X$, which by the previous argument has to be zero on the exceptional component $E$. However, it is clearly an isomorphism away from $E$. It follows that $\mathcal{O}(1)|_{Y} \simeq \mathcal{O}_Y(-p-q)$ if $p,q$ are the preimages of the node.